# Divide string to a few equal substrings

Tags: javascript

Here is a code to find years which January the 1st is Monday

```
var targetYear = "";
var targetLength;
for (var i = 2014; i < 2050; i++)  {
    var d = new Date(i, 0, 1).getDay();
    if (d === 1) {
      targetYear += i;
    }
}
targetLength = targetYear.length;
```

I got a string in which every four numbers mean the year.
Is there any way to split this string into a number of strings and assign each to variable?
This way:

```
for (var i = 2014; i < 2050; i++)  {
    var d = new Date(i, 1, 1).getDay();
    if (d === 1) {
      console.log("The year "+ i +" Jan the 1st is Monday");
    }
}
```

It works perfectly in console but if I try:

```
document.getElementById('congrats').innerHTML = "The year "+ i +" Jan the 1st is Monday"
```

only  the last one result is displayed. Not each.

Comment: `getDay() === 0` means Sunday, not Monday

Comment: document.getElementById('congrats').innerHTML = "The year "+ i +" Jan the 1st is Monday" will always update the content in the same div. Its not creating various divs. Thats why its showing the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('congrats').innerHTML = "The year "+ i +" Jan the 1st is Monday"
```

This is only displaying the last result because on each iteration of the for loop, the contents of `innerHTML` are being replaced.

**A better solution instead of using `innerHTML` is to use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).**

Unlike `innerHTML`, `insertAdjacentHTML` does not reparse the entire HTML each time like `innerHTML` does. This makes `insertAdjacentHTML` much faster than `innerHTML`:

```js
 for (var i = 2014; i < 2050; i++) {
   var d = new Date(i, 0, 1).getDay();
   if (d === 1) {
      document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "The year "+ i +" Jan the 1st is Monday<br>")

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('congrats').innerHTML = "The year "+ i +" Jan the 1st is Monday"
```

Your problem is that you are replacing the innerHTML value on every loop so obviously only last result will be displayed because it is not being replaced.

```
document.getElementById('congrats').innerHTML += "The year "+ i +" Jan the 1st is Monday\n"
```

You can do this to concatenate the innerHTML assuming the HTML element used is pre tag.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kkt3sz5e/)

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('congrats').innerHTML = "The year "+ i +" Jan the 1st is Monday"

its means its overwrite the old code so instead of this line you can use below line

document.getElementById('congrats').innerHTML + = "The year "+ i +" Jan the 1st is Monday"